# trans codes trans not shifting o/d is blinking

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, p1747, p0755, p0743

I have a trans problem my truck lost power o/d light is blinking and trans does not shift at all it has codes that are p1747 p0755 p0743

Comment: I already changed the shift soldod

Comment: Make model year?

Comment: You say "it lost power" what exactly do you mean by that? Or do you mean by not going into O/D, the vehicle speed is not as it should be? Just wondering if there might be an engine problem causing it to go into *limp home mode* which would not allow it to shift up into O/D ... Long shot considering the codes, but thought is throw it out there.

Comment: If you use a newer transmission in a older application The pressure signal return ect is in a different wiring diagram than your original it will make it feel like a 4cyl - the shift solenoids will not work correctly lock up convertor ect. I went from 96-2000 there different on passenger side plugs don't try it unless u know something I don't. The late model has 7 pins for pass side plug . The other has 10 and yes I pulled a diagram the clutch solinoid is the only thing that wired up right. Hope helps someone I'm changing it again today more $$$ down the drain over Ford's frequent changing .

Answer (score 1):

P1747 - Electronic Pressure Control Solenoid - Short circuit

P0755 - Shift Solenoid 'B' Malfunction

P0743 Torque Converter Clutch (TCC) Solenoid Circuit Electrical

Before you changed the shift solenoid, you had the same errors? 
Short circuit could happen because of broken shift solenoid. Could also be an electrically error in EPC.

Comment: yes same codes before and after I changed shift soldod truck will rev in park or n in gear no power it bearly will go

Comment: one trans guy said it the motor loss of power making trans go into limp mode I don't think so I changed all plugs,coils,fuel pump,fuel filter I think trans is chocking motor down any help

Comment: the truck is 2001 ford f150 4.6 auto

Comment: The thing I would try is to disconnect the shift solenoid, erase all errors and watch what he would say. If you still have the same problems, there is something wrong with the cable to shift solenoid or with the control unit for them. Other way I can not explain this short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out to be a 15a fuse under the hood. The transmission fuse. As soon as i changed the fuse it ran like before.